# Emulate coercion to string as seen with Date and Location instances

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, instantiation, tostring

[I've written a little script that converts any given URI-like string into a DOM object similar to that received by `window.location`](https://gist.github.com/barneycarroll/5310151). This is achieved by using the DOM to create an anchor element, assigning the passed string to its `href` property, and then copying out all static properties that are present in both anchor elements and the `window.location` element.

I later noticed that `window.location` is an `instanceof` the mysterious `Location` object, but attempting to invoke `Location` is illegal. For fun, I decided to override the `Location` object and change my function's API to match native DOM constructor style.

One of the nice (or horrible, depending on perspective) things about DOM objects like `Location` and `Date` is their non-standard implementation of `toString`, which appears to be invoked behind the scenes when certain operators are invoked:

```
var x = window.location + '?querystring' // => 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?querystring';
```

I can't seem to emulate this kind of behaviour.

My first attempt was:

```
Location.prototype.toString = function toString(){ return this.href };
```

This is the only solution I've found which emulates `window.location.toString()` direct invocation, but obviously I've lost all binding to the original prototype internals, so returning the `href` on explicit invocation is *all* it does.

So I thought I needed to apply my custom `Location` to the native `toString` behaviour of Location, but:

```
Location.prototype.toString = function toStringClosure(){
    // Can't use `Function.prototype.bind` because we need
    // the closure to invoke `this`. Javascript is awesome.
    return ( new Location() ).toString.call( this );
}
```

…will tell you that executing `Location` is illegal or invalid. Of course. But what about:

```
Location.prototype.toString = function toStringClosure(){
    return ( new Date() ).toString.call( this );
}
```

No, `this is not an instance of Date`. This implies extra-special privileges in native objects, or maybe just a nice opaque wrapper around "I tried to look for other Date internals that Date.prototype.toString actually aliases to, but couldn't find them".

However, querying the prototype without *executing* the Date or Location constructors reveals something else:

```
Location.prototype.toString = function toStringClosure(){
    return Location.prototype.toString.call( this );
}
```

Namely, `Function.prototype.toString is not generic`. Yeah I know, that's why I specifically invoked the non-generic `Location` variety. This leads me to believe that the internals of these objects don't actually play by the normal rules of inheritance, or indeed Javascript execution (after all, direct property assignment with `window.location = x` will implicitly execute `window.location.assign( x )` — I suppose this is similar to `setAttribute` with certain nodes, but they remain essentially read-write).

So: is there any way I can emulate the magical string coercion displayed by direct operations on Date and Location objects?

And: how do the last 2 snippets of code play out internally? Are there internal relationships and code properties at work there that cannot be expressed in pure JS?

Comment: This sound like and XY-problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem - in general you shouldn't rely on coercion or a specific `toString` implementation. It can be nice for debugging but don't use it for anything else.

Comment: What is the problem with `Date`? I can't comprehend...

Comment: @xanatos `Date` is fine (although it's much easier to work with with chaining wrappers like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)). The question has more to do with `Location`. That's also fine, but I want to know how to emulate its string coercion properties.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen true, but that's more of a 'bonus points' / 'incidentally…' follow up — more to placate "show your working" type comments in advance. You're onto something with "you shouldn't rely on coercion", but browser inconsistencies are somewhat besides the point — I'm just trying to provide an API that's consistent with whatever environment it's executed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point in my investigations I got lax. My first attempt was:

```
Location.prototype.toString = function toString(){ return this.href };
```

…And it turns out this is all that is necessary: when an object is an operand in an operation in which the other operand is not of the same type, the following properties will be invoked in sequence to see if an operation is feasible:

1. `valueOf`
2. `toString`

Javascript looks for the `toString` method, finds it and executes it and attempts the operation there. So in fact, under my current revision, if I run:

```
new Location('/root') + '?query=string';
```

…I will get:

```
"http://stackoverflow.com/root?query=string"
```

Sorted!

Comment: @xanatos You mean valueOf if you fill an array with objects that implement valueOf then valueOf is used in operators such as >,<,==,<=,>= but if you call sort() on that array than toString is used. In forefox at least.

Comment: @HMR yes, `valueOf` is useful if there's a numeric equivalent you want to be aware of for operations like that. In type coercion scenarios like the above it would get invoked before attempting `toString` (useful for `Date`s), but it's of a muchness as far as I'm concerned — `window.location.valueOf()` will return the full object, and that's the interface I'm emulating.

Comment: @HMR incorporating your mention of `valueOf` into the answer for completeness.